# In Read uncommitted transaction, select statement hold S lock

Tags: mysql, transactions, locking

I changed my select statement transaction to read uncommitted but still it holds shared lock and get involved in deadlock with another update statement,

Select statements are in whatsnew(uid,friend_news_id,actor_news_id) SP

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED ;

 set @actor_news_limit = 2;
 set @player_news_limit = 6;


if (select
    n.id

from
    news n 
inner join
    news_user_xrf nu
on 
    n.id = nu.news_id
inner join
    friends f
 on
    nu.user_id = f.friend_id
 inner join 
    user u
 on 
    u.id = f.friend_id
 where
    f.user_id = uid
 and
    n.id > friend_news_id
 order by
    n.points desc,n.newsDate desc
 limit 0,1) is null

then



select * from
(select
    n.id,
    'whatshot_friendsnews' as type,
    n.content,
    '0' as actor_id,
    u.id as player_id,
    n.newsType,
    n.like_text,
    n.link,
    n.newsDate,
    u.imgurl,
    u.firstname,
    u.lastname,
    n.points
from
    news n 
inner join
    news_user_xrf nu
on 
    n.id = nu.news_id

 inner join 
    user u
 on 
    u.id = nu.user_id

 where
    u.id <> uid

 and
    n.id > friend_news_id
 order by
    n.newsDate desc
 limit 0,3) a order by newsDate;

else


select * from
(select
    n.id,
    'whatshot_friendsnews' as type,
    n.content,
    '0' as actor_id,
    u.id as player_id,
    n.newsType,
    n.like_text,
    n.link,
    n.newsDate,
    u.imgurl,
    u.firstname,
    u.lastname,
    n.points
from
    news n 
inner join
    news_user_xrf nu
on 
    n.id = nu.news_id
inner join
    friends f
 on
    nu.user_id = f.friend_id
 inner join 
    user u
 on 
    u.id = f.friend_id
 where
    f.user_id = uid
 and
    n.id > friend_news_id
 order by
    n.points desc,n.newsDate desc
 limit 0,3) a order by newsDate;



end if;

select * from
(select 
    n.id,
    'whatshot_actornews' as type,
    n.content,
    na.actor_id,
    "0" as player_id,
    n.newsType,
    n.like_text,
    n.link,
    n.newsDate,
    n.newsImg as imgurl,
    '' as firstname,
    ''  as lastname,
    n.points

from
    news n
inner join
    news_actor_xrf na
on 
    n.id = na.news_id
where 
    newsType = 2
and
    n.id > actor_news_id
order by 
    points desc,
    newsDate desc
limit 
    0,3
)  a order by newsDate;

COMMIT ;

END
```

now i have another update statement where i update same table and this statement wait for X lock but it cannot have it as the whatsnew sp holds S lock on the same table, 
    below is Update sp

```
set SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;

update user
set networth = (select sum(p.avgcostprice * p.quantity) 
from portfolio p where p.user_id = user.id) +
(select truncate(sum((a.currentvalue - p.avgcostprice)*p.quantity),2)  
from actor a inner join portfolio p on a.id = p.actor_id where p.user_id = user.id) +
user.balance;


update user u
  set u.rank = (select count(*) from friends f 
 where ifnull(friend_networth,0) > user_networth
and f.user_id = u.id) + 1;

update user u
set u.rank_text = (select concat(u.rank,'/',(select
count(*)+1 from friends f where f.user_id = u.id)));
```

Now both of these stored procedure gets involved in deadlock, but question is even when i am using read uncommitted why select statement
 holds Shared lock on the rows, it should read( dirty read) from the
 table. here is SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS output

```
=====================================
2014-07-06 03:44:57 2ad677681700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 2 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 32811 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 89228 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 122039
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 22814
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 21778
Mutex spin waits 6627, rounds 508985, OS waits 15885
RW-shared spins 5876, rounds 176305, OS waits 5659
RW-excl spins 44, rounds 38079, OS waits 1237
Spin rounds per wait: 76.80 mutex, 30.00 RW-shared, 865.43 RW-excl
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2014-07-06 02:01:41 2ad677681700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 1925770, ACTIVE 0 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
LOCK WAIT 25 lock struct(s), heap size 3112, 909 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 28709, OS thread handle 0x2ad677640700, query id 349542 ec2-54-226-145-7.compute-1.amazonaws.com 54.227.116.3 Database1 Searching rows for update
update user u
set u.rank_text = (select concat(u.rank,''/'',(select
count(*)+1 from friends f where f.user_id = u.id)))
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 19303 page no 29 n bits 104 index `PRIMARY` of table `Database1`.`user` trx id 1925770 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 31 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 25; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 8000000000000416; asc         ;;
 1: len 6; hex 0000001d214a; asc     !J;;
 2: len 7; hex 6f0000018d08f9; asc o      ;;
 3: len 8; hex 80005af4001478e8; asc   Z   x ;;
 4: len 5; hex 5269736869; asc Rishi;;
 5: len 5; hex 506174656c; asc Patel;;
 6: len 23; hex 7269736869706174656c5f3939407961686f6f2e636f6d; asc rishi_9999@yahoo.com;;
 7: len 30; hex 43414146336348376866544942414a434844466b5a42664937544a554643; asc CAAF3cH7hfTIBAJCHDFkZBfI7TJUFC; (total 201 bytes);
 8: len 8; hex 800000005405f359; asc     T  Y;;
 9: len 9; hex 80000000000007d619; asc          ;;
 10: len 1; hex 01; asc  ;;
 11: len 30; hex 313034383539303739377c3130303030303937303735313938317c313030; asc 1048590797|100000970751981|100; (total 58 bytes);
 12: len 30; hex 68747470733a2f2f67726170682e66616365626f6f6b2e636f6d2f313030; asc https://graph.facebook.com/100; (total 50 bytes);
 13: SQL NULL;
 14: len 4; hex 80000002; asc     ;;
 15: len 4; hex 466f4145; asc FoAE;;
 16: SQL NULL;
 17: len 4; hex 00000000; asc     ;;
 18: len 3; hex 322f35; asc 2/5;;
 19: SQL NULL;
 20: len 8; hex 8000000000000007; asc         ;;
 21: len 4; hex 05c58045; asc    E;;
 22: SQL NULL;
 23: len 8; hex 8000000000000000; asc         ;;
 24: len 8; hex 8000000000000007; asc         ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 1925761, ACTIVE 22 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 4, locked 4
14 lock struct(s), heap size 3112, 4 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 28723, OS thread handle 0x2ad677681700, query id 349517 ec2-54-91-34-208.compute-1.amazonaws.com 54.91.34.208 Database1 Sending data
call whatsnew(uid,friend_news_id,actor_news_id)
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 19303 page no 29 n bits 104 index `PRIMARY` of table `Database1`.`user` trx id 1925761 lock mode S locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 31 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 25; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 8000000000000416; asc         ;;
 1: len 6; hex 0000001d214a; asc     !J;;
 2: len 7; hex 6f0000018d08f9; asc o      ;;
 3: len 8; hex 80005af4001478e8; asc   Z   x ;;
 4: len 5; hex 5269736869; asc Rishi;;
 5: len 5; hex 506174656c; asc Patel;;
 6: len 23; hex 7269736869706174656c5f3939407961686f6f2e636f6d; asc rishi_9999@yahoo.com;;
 7: len 30; hex 43414146336348376866544942414a434844466b5a42664937544a554643; asc CAAF3cH7hfTIBAJCHDFkZBfI7TJUFC; (total 201 bytes);
 8: len 8; hex 800000005405f359; asc     T  Y;;
 9: len 9; hex 80000000000007d619; asc          ;;
 10: len 1; hex 01; asc  ;;
 11: len 30; hex 313034383539303739377c3130303030303937303735313938317c313030; asc 1048590797|100000970751981|100; (total 58 bytes);
 12: len 30; hex 68747470733a2f2f67726170682e66616365626f6f6b2e636f6d2f313030; asc https://graph.facebook.com/100; (total 50 bytes);
 13: SQL NULL;
 14: len 4; hex 80000002; asc     ;;
 15: len 4; hex 466f4145; asc FoAE;;
 16: SQL NULL;
 17: len 4; hex 00000000; asc     ;;
 18: len 3; hex 322f35; asc 2/5;;
 19: SQL NULL;
 20: len 8; hex 8000000000000007; asc         ;;
 21: len 4; hex 05c58045; asc    E;;
 22: SQL NULL;
 23: len 8; hex 8000000000000000; asc         ;;
 24: len 8; hex 8000000000000007; asc         ;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 19303 page no 29 n bits 104 index `PRIMARY` of table `Database1`.`user` trx id 1925761 lock mode S locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 26 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 25; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 800000000000040b; asc         ;;
 1: len 6; hex 0000001d214a; asc     !J;;
 2: len 7; hex 6f0000018d0878; asc o     x;;
 3: len 8; hex 80005af401790e35; asc   Z  y 5;;
 4: len 3; hex 52616a; asc Raj;;
 5: len 5; hex 506174656c; asc Patel;;
 6: len 22; hex 706174656c3039303972616a407961686f6f2e636f6d; asc patel@yahoo.com;;
 7: len 30; hex 434141463363483768665449424145726535315545495475473766556652; asc CAAF3cH7hfTIBAEre51UEITuG7fUfR; (total 199 bytes);
 8: len 8; hex 8000000054060653; asc     T  S;;
 9: len 9; hex 800000000000098440; asc         @;;
 10: len 1; hex 01; asc  ;;
 11: len 30; hex 313034383539303739377c313432343530303835307c3130303030303937; asc 1048590797|1424500850|10000097; (total 85 bytes);
 12: len 30; hex 68747470733a2f2f67726170682e66616365626f6f6b2e636f6d2f313030; asc graph.facebook.com/10000; (total 50 bytes);
 13: SQL NULL;
 14: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 15: SQL NULL;
 16: SQL NULL;
 17: len 4; hex 00000000; asc     ;;
 18: len 3; hex 312f37; asc 1/7;;
 19: len 4; hex 00000000; asc     ;;
 20: len 8; hex 8000000000000018; asc         ;;
 21: len 4; hex 6bdb7e45; asc k ~E;;
 22: SQL NULL;
 23: len 8; hex 8000000000000000; asc         ;;
 24: len 8; hex 8000000000000018; asc         ;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 1929046
Purge done for trx''s n:o < 1929045 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 1711
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 0, not started
MySQL thread id 28864, OS thread handle 0x2ad677681700, query id 357530 122.169.237.65 Database1 init
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
---TRANSACTION 1929043, not started
MySQL thread id 28863, OS thread handle 0x2ad677640700, query id 357529 ec2-54-226-145-7.compute-1.amazonaws.com 54.227.116.3 Database1 creating table
create table temp_ceiling (actor_id int, p_change float, cval float, fval float)
---TRANSACTION 1929042, not started
MySQL thread id 28859, OS thread handle 0x2ad675ee3700, query id 357510 localhost 127.0.0.1 rdsadmin cleaning up
---TRANSACTION 1929045, ACTIVE 0 sec committing foreign key definitions
5 lock struct(s), heap size 1248, 0 row lock(s), undo log entries 8
MySQL thread id 28863, OS thread handle 0x2ad677640700, query id 357529 ec2-54-226-145-7.compute-1.amazonaws.com 54.227.116.3 Database1 creating table
create table temp_ceiling (actor_id int, p_change float, cval float, fval float)
TABLE LOCK table `SYS_TABLES` trx id 1929045 lock mode IX
TABLE LOCK table `SYS_COLUMNS` trx id 1929045 lock mode IX
TABLE LOCK table `SYS_TABLESPACES` trx id 1929045 lock mode IX
TABLE LOCK table `SYS_DATAFILES` trx id 1929045 lock mode IX
TABLE LOCK table `SYS_INDEXES` trx id 1929045 lock mode IX
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for completed aio requests (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for completed aio requests (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 ibuf aio reads: 0, log i/o''s: 0, sync i/o''s: 0
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
946 OS file reads, 122080 OS file writes, 61052 OS fsyncs
0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 4000.00 writes/s, 5000.00 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 0, seg size 2, 0 merges
merged operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
discarded operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 612301, node heap has 33 buffer(s)
0.00 hash searches/s, 5.00 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 502059361
Log flushed up to   502055320
Pages flushed up to 502053286
Last checkpoint at  502053286
0 pending log writes, 0 pending chkp writes
39359 log i/o''s done, 1.00 log i/o''s/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total memory allocated 316588032; in additional pool allocated 0
Dictionary memory allocated 269802
Buffer pool size   18880
Free buffers       11148
Database pages     7699
Old database pages 2822
Modified db pages  16
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 886, created 6813, written 73085
0.00 reads/s, 4000.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 7699, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[1], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
0 read views open inside InnoDB
Main thread process no. 18631, id 47100585178880, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 43271, updated 151830, deleted 2009, read 7297650700
0.00 inserts/s, 14.49 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 167000.00 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
'
```

please help